# How to display a users post on home page

Tags: html, user-interface, display

So at the top of the page there is an area for users to create a post with a title and body.

```
<div class="write_post" id="write_post">
        <label for="post_title"><b>Title</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="What are you calling this?" name="post_title" required>

        <label for="post_body">Body</label>
        <textarea name="post_body" id="post_body" rows="5" cols="80" placeholder="Write post here..." required></textarea>

        <button action="post.php" class="post_submit" type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
```

The goal is when they click the post button it will create a post below.
I've tried using javascript to help, but I'm not 100% sure what to do. A push in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use JavaScript in this case – you can use **PHP** and save the form data in a **database**.

### 1. Create an HTML form within a PHP file

First, wrap your input elements in a **form** (I've only kept the elements that are important in this case):

`index.php`

```
<form action="comment.php" method="get">

        <input type="text" name="post_title">

        <textarea name="post_body"></textarea>

        <button type="submit">Post</button>

</form>
```

---

### 2. Create a PHP file to process the submitted form data

As you can see, the form has an action attribute which leads to a file named **comment.php**. This is just a suitable name I picked, you can name the PHP-file however you like.

In this newly created PHP-file you have to process the submitted form data. Please notice that PHP-files can only run on a server and not locally on your PC like an HTML-file. I would recommend to directly upload and test within a sub-folder on your web server.

A possible folder structure would be:

```
test-folder
 |
 +-- index.php
 |
 +-- comment.php
```

---

### 2. Editing the PHP file and saving data to the database

Open the PHP-File and add the following:

`comment.php`

#### 2.1 Getting the form data

```
?php

/* 
 * Receive the submitted form data and assign it to variables
 */


$comment_title = $_GET["post_title"]; // same as the name attribute in HTML
$comment_body = $_GET["post_body"];
```

#### 2.2 Creating a new database

We now have the data, but we also want to save it. Data like this is usually saved within a database. Most hosting providers allow you to create one pretty easily.

Your database should have a structure like this:

```
comments
 |
 +-- ID (auto increment)
 |
 +-- comment_title
 |
 +-- comment_body
```

#### 2.3 Connecting to the database

We now have to connect to our database to save the data.

```
/* 
 * Connect to your database to save the form data
 */

$servername = "localhost"; // get this data from your hosting provider 
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// create a new connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// check if the connection succeeds
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

#### 2.4 Inserting data in to the database

```
/* 
 * Insert the form data in to the database
 */

$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (comment_title, comment_body)
VALUES ('".$comment_title."','".$comment_body."',)";

$conn->close();
```

---

### 3. Displaying the saved data

Now we only have to display the saved data on the index.php
We can to this by looping through the rows in our database.

`index.php`

```
/* 
 * Connect to your database and display the saved comments
 */

$servername = "localhost"; // get this data from your hosting provider 
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// create a new connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// check if the connection succeeds
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT comment_title, comment_body FROM comments");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0] . $row[1];  
}
```